# How to use a message including a custom format definition with Protocol Buffers for Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, python-3.5

I am trying to develop a client using Protocol Buffers to communicate with a server over a MQTT communication.

I did a small test with a subset of the protocol and it doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

**The protocol definition:**

```
syntax = "proto2";

message EventHeader {
    // Gw id that generated the event
    required string gw_id = 1;
    // Sink id if relevant for event
    optional string sink_id = 2;
    // Random event id to help duplicate event filtering
    required uint64 event_id = 3;
}

enum OnOffState {
    ON = 1;
    OFF = 2;
}

message StatusEvent {
    required EventHeader header = 1;
    required uint32 version = 2;
    required OnOffState state = 3;
}
```

**The python code generated by protoc**:

```
from protobuf3.message import Message
from protobuf3.fields import EnumField, StringField, UInt64Field, MessageField, UInt32Field
from enum import Enum


class EventHeader(Message):
    pass


class StatusEvent(Message):
    pass


class OnOffState(Enum):
    ON = 1
    OFF = 2

EventHeader.add_field('gw_id', StringField(field_number=1, required=True))
EventHeader.add_field('sink_id', StringField(field_number=2, optional=True))
EventHeader.add_field('event_id', UInt64Field(field_number=3, required=True))
StatusEvent.add_field('header', MessageField(field_number=1, required=True, message_cls=EventHeader))
StatusEvent.add_field('version', UInt32Field(field_number=2, required=True))
StatusEvent.add_field('state', EnumField(field_number=3, required=True, enum_cls=OnOffState))
```

**The Python code using the message defined**

```
msg = message.StatusEvent()
header = msg.header

header.gw_id = 'gateway_test'
header.event_id=random.randint(0,2**64-1)

header.sink_id='sink_test'
msg.version = 0
msg.version = message.OnOffState.ON
```

**The error I get**:

```
  File "/home/dc/svn/Code/APS/Application/BigBrother/trunk/Client.py", line 23, in run
    header.gw_id = 'gateway_test'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf3/fields/base.py", line 87, in __set__
    self._convert_to_wire_type(value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf3/message.py", line 185, in _set_wire_values
    msg._set_wire_values(number, FIELD_VARIABLE_LENGTH, self.encode_to_bytes(), idx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf3/message.py", line 204, in encode_to_bytes
    self._check_required_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf3/message.py", line 159, in _check_required_fields
    raise KeyError("Some required fields are missing: " + ", ".join(missing_fields))
KeyError: 'Some required fields are missing: event_id'
```

I don't understand how I am supposed to initialize my message with data. When I try to fill in one field, python systematically crashes telling me I first have to initialize another field.

I use Python 3.5.2 for this test.

I based by work on [this page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial)

Comment: This looks like a bug in protobuf3 lib. Note that this is a 3rd party library that is not under Google's maintanance. You may want to try the official lib: https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/ instead. Although I'm not sure how well it supports Python 3.x (even though they claim it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf3 you were using is an archived project https://github.com/Pr0Ger/protobuf3. Please use pypi.org/project/protobuf.

Comment: Thank you !
But the thing I don't understand is that when I build the message.py from the message.proto with protoc, I always have the protobuf3 import, not the protobuf import (which is also installed on my computer...)
How should I force protoc to use protobuf ? (I use the last stable release of protoc, so libprotoc 3.6.1)

Comment: Ok, I found the solution: I was compiling message.proto using "python3_out=" argument instead of "python_out=". Because of the argument "python3_out=", protoc was using protobuf3 instead of protobuf.
Now it works as expected